# What's the best flex 4 book?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

I have already the Adobe Flex 3 bible and would up to speed with Flex 4 and learn the new stuff. 
Which of these books should I buy?

### [Developing Flex 4 Components](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/032160413X)

[image]

### [Effortless Flex 4 Development](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321705947)

[image]

### [Flex 4 Fun](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0981531628)

[image]

Comment: It depends on what kind of apps you're going to be building for the most part. Form based apps? Animation? Games? Mobile?

Comment: I have an idea firstly to build an admin panel that you can upload and manage all your pictures through drag and drop.

Comment: I bought the Effortless Flex 4 Development, mostly because of Larry Ullmans positive reviews on all his books. He seems like to be a good writer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I had to pick from that list, I'd go with **Developing Flex 4 Components**.

You may also want to consider [Enterprise Development with Flex: Best Practices for RIA Developers (Adobe Dev Lib)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/059615416X).